# jq: Select range

Tags: arrays, json, slice, jq

TL;DR: Given an input file with a series of keypairs, I want to select the 3rd-to-last and 4th-to-last pairs. I can get them individually, but I want to grab both at once if possible. Can this be done?

My input file is structured like this;

```
[
 {
  "foo": "bar",
  "foo2": "bar2"
 },
 {
  "foo3": "bar3",
  "foo4": "bar4"
 },
 {
  "foo5": "bar5",
  "foo6": "bar6"
 },
 {
  "foo7": "bar7",
  "foo8": "bar8"
 },
 {
  "foo9": "bar9",
  "foo10": "bar10"
 }
]
```

And my output should be

```
[ 
 {
  "foo3": "bar3",
  "foo4": "bar4"
 },
 {
  "foo5": "bar5",
  "foo6": "bar6"
 }
]
```

I know I can do `jq -s '.[-3]'` to get the 3rd-to-last (and swap with a 4 for the 4th-to-last) but that grabs them separately.

I thought from the documentation that `jq -s '.[-3;-4]'` would grab both but that throws an error.

I could grab them individually and work on each separately but that's sloppy code. Is there a cleaner way to grab both at once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Drop the -s option.  Your input is already an array.
2. The filter to use: [.[-3,-4]]

Explanation: `.[a,b]` is like `.[a],.[b]`.  The outer brackets turn this into an array.

Any number of indices may be specified in this manner, and the order in which they are presented will determine the order of the items in the result.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to select ranges of values in an array, you could use the slice syntax:

```
<start-index>:<end-index>
```

Just remember that the ending index is exclusive (and not inclusive) and should be increasing order.

So to get the third/fourth from the end:

```
.[-4:-2]
```